# sed, replace in linux http://cdn1 with https://cdn1

Tags: linux, sed

I want to replace `http://cdn1.domain.com` with `https://cdn1.domain.com` in 200 .html files and I don't know how to do that with sed.

Can somebody help me with this?

```
sed -i '/http:/\/\cdn1/http:/\/\cdn1/' cum-comand.html
sed: -e expression #1, char 8: unknown command: `\'

sed -i '/http:\/\/cdn1/http:\/\/cdn1/' cum-comand.html
sed: -e expression #1, char 17: extra characters after command
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10445934/change-multiple-files

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please edit your question and include what you've tried and why it didn't work.

Comment: sed -i '/http:/\/\cdn1/http:/\/\cdn1/' cum-comand.html
sed: -e expression #1, char 8: unknown command: `\'
sed -i '/http:\/\/cdn1/http:\/\/cdn1/' cum-comand.html
sed: -e expression #1, char 17: extra characters after command

Comment: You have reversed your slashes and backslashes.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If they are in same directory, you can just do this:

```
sed -i 's|http://cdn1.domain.com|https://cdn1.domain.com|g' *.html
```

If not, run find:

```
find . -name "*.html" -exec sed -i 's|http://cdn1.domain.com|https://cdn1.domain.com|g' {} \;
```